# Connecting Raspberry Pi 3 with Huawei Surfstick 372

Tags: pi-3, usb, internet, chromium

I tried to connect my Raspberry Pi with the Huawei Surfstick. All the tutorials i watched so far didn't helped me. If i plug in the Surfstick the raspberry shows that it is associated with it and has an ip. But when i try to open a website like google it says website cant be reached. I followed some other tutorials and my /etc/network/interface looks different. There is only a path to 
`source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d` another unusual thing is that if i type in the command route it says:

```
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     205    0        0 wwan0
```

and the default option is all 0. Some Tutorials also say that i have to download wvdial or sakis3g or ppp to connect to the surfstick but im unable to download these files: it says the packages are not available and they cannot be found. 
Does anybody has a solution to these problems? Thank you for the support and sorry for bad english.

**edit:** if i type `ip a` it shows:

```
4: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:49:e3:08:53:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::4fdf:4ab6:ebf4:be67/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

i also tried to ping to 8.8.8.8 or www.google.de but it also didn't help it says "*unknown Host*".
**edit 2.0:**
if i type in the command route it shows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route<br>
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle<br>
Ziel    --------Router         --- Genmask       --  Flags--- Metric Ref    Use Iface<br>
default       --  0.0.0.0      -----   0.0.0.0     -------    U    ------- 204    ---0       --- 0 --wwan0
<br>link-local      0.0.0.0        --- 255.255.0.0     ---U     --------204  --  0  ----      0 --wwan0
<br></brodcast>
```

**edit3.0**: 
when typing: ip show route:

```
default dev wwan0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.2.14 metric 204
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwan0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.2.14 metric 204<br></brodcast>
```

and ip addr show:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000<br>
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00<br>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo<br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host <br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br><br>
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000<br>
    link/ether b8:27:eb:cc:4b:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff<br><br>
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000<br>
    link/ether b8:27:eb:99:1e:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff<br><br>
4: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000<br>
    link/ether be:90:ed:11:c1:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff<br>
    inet 169.254.2.14/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global wwan0<br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
    inet6 fe80::2152:9df6:6360:27d1/64 scope link <br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br><br></brodcast>
```

I hope this shows some good things. Thank you for the support!

**Final edit:** 
@Ingo helped me to find the Problem. It was the Surfstick that caused it. I took another Surfstick with the same SIM Card and it worked. If somebody has the same problem try that out i hope it helps someone and it doesen t takes you 3 whole days to figure it out ^^.

Comment: what does the command `ip a` show? im my case the Surf Stick appears as interface `eth1` with valid ip address.

Comment: it shows: 4: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:3f:bf:05:f4:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.69.208/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global wwan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e25d:74b8:5dd7:58e4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: Your comment is unreadable. Please edit your question and add the output of the command there.

Comment: `4: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:49:e3:08:53:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::4fdf:4ab6:ebf4:be67/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: @Ingo is this better ? Im sorry this is my first question/comment

Comment: No, it is not better. Please do what I suggested: edit your **question** above. Under your qestion are some links `share edit flag`. Please tick the `edit` link there and insert the output. Btw. it is a good idea to take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Ingo i have finally found the button ^^

Comment: Nice :-) Now we can help better. I have reformatted the question a bit. But we need complete information. Neither routing information nor address information are complete. Please give us unexpurgated information. I suppose you have a routing problem. Btw. your **wwan0** interface has no ip address and it isn't member of a bridge. So this cannot work.

Comment: @Ingo thx :). Yeah i thought he had a real one but now i have read that the 169.xxx ip- Addresses like my Pi has with the surfstick isnt a real IP-Address atleast not the one that has access to the internet ^^.

Comment: The more we try to clear up details the more it get confused. You tell something about a [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) from 169.254.0.0/16 but I only see 10.55.128.0 from the routing table but the interface has no ip address. This all makes no sense. To get an overview what's going on with your setup I need the output of `ip addr show` and `ip route show` namely complete one and not crippled. This should be executed when you have established a connection with the surfstick to your provider.

Comment: And please have a look at the short formating hints for *markdown* you will find when editing the question.

Comment: @Ingo the 10.55.128.0 comes from the Wlan i guess i had turned it on when i copied it. I now have edited it

Comment: @Ingo and sorry for the bad formating but I couldn t find how to make a tab in the help Cathalog...

Comment: The surfstick simply doesn't work. There is no connection to your provider.  Btw. you use quoting to format. Just indent with 4 spaces to get code blocks. Then there is no need to use html tags.

Comment: @Ingo ok i will do that. So you say that my Surfstick just doesn t work ?

Comment: Yes. The **wwan** interface has a link-local address that is given when no other connection is available. link-local addresses are not routable, cannot be send to the internet. You must also have a default route to a gateway with ip address from your provider. There is no ip address for a gateway given on your default route.

Comment: @Ingo WOW! You were right. I change the Surfstick and look at that it worked ... But I don t understand why because i didn t change the Sim Card ... Does that mean the Surfstick is broken ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your surfstick doesn't work. There is a **wwan** interface available that shows that the hardware is recognized and a driver is loaded. But the interface has only a [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) that is given when no other connection is available. Link-local addresses are only usable for local networks without router and cannot be routed to other networks or to the internet. With a connection to your provider you also must have a default route to the gateway of the provider so network packages to the internet are send to this gateway. Your default route shows:

```
default dev wwan0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.2.14 metric 204
```

It does not have a gateway ip address. It should look something like this:

```
default via 10.20.30.1 dev wwan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.30.40 metric 204
```

This also indicates that you do not have a connection to your provider. So at first to get it running you have to configure the surfstick to establish a connection to your provider. You should have got information from it something like a user/link/network name or password. I cannot help you with this because I don't know something about the surfstick and provider.

Comment: @benipro98 As you wrote in the comment to the question you have got it to run with another surfstick. Maybe the first one is broken or you have different surfsticks and they need different setups.